# Entity Framework и foreign key

Tags: entity-framework

Добрый вечер. У меня снова вопрос по Entity Framework

Допустим я имею два класса из которых ORM должна создать две таблицы в БД. При этом одна из таблиц должна иметь внешний ключ ссылающийся на первую таблицу. Как это реализовать? Знаю что имеется атрибут ForeignKey но не пойму как он работает - у него есть только имя? но как задать на какое поле в какой таблице он ссылается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На хабре выкладывался [цикл статей](https://habr.com/en/post/136328/) по Code First. Если я вас правильно понял, посмотрите на [первую статью](https://web.archive.org/web/20151208044002/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vyunev/archive/2011/10/04/entity-framework-asp-net-mvc.aspx) из цикла.